# Adding a column indicating a "1" or "0" based on values from a query in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm currently trying to add a value to a column indicating if a customer is a VIP or not, VIP customers have placed 10 or more orders. 1 = VIP, 0 = non-vip.

I've written this query that successfully returns a column providing the order count for each customer ID.

```
SELECT *
FROM customer;

SELECT customer.customer_id, customer_name, address_line_1, city, state_province, count(order_header.customer_id) AS ordercount
FROM customer
    LEFT JOIN order_header ON customer.customer_id = order_header.customer_id
    GROUP BY customer.customer_id;
```

How can I change this to indicate a "1" for customers with >= 10 orders, and a "0" for everyone else?

This query uses a subquery, but the "ordercount" column is 6,921 (the total number of orders) for every row.

```
WITH OrderCountTable AS
(
    SELECT customer.customer_id, customer_name, address_line_1, city, state_province, count(order_header.customer_id) AS ordercount
    FROM order_header, customer
    GROUP BY customer.customer_id
)
SELECT *
FROM OrderCountTable
WHERE ordercount >= 10;
```

I'm stumped and not sure how to accomplish my goal, I feel like I'm overcomplicating this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update #1 based on Akina's Comment**

```
FROM (SELECT customer.customer_id, customer_name, address_line_1, city, state_province, count(order_header.customer_id) AS ordercount
    FROM customer
    LEFT JOIN order_header ON customer.customer_id = order_header.customer_id 
    GROUP BY customer.customer_id) AS vipTable
```

This returns the proper dataset, but the isVIP is false on every row. Did I misplace something?

---

Comment: *`FROM order_header, customer`* .. and where is joining condition?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id) >= 10 AS isVIP
FROM {tableset with proper joining}
```

In practice it can be, for example,

```
SELECT customer.column1, .. , customer.columnN, COUNT(*) >= 10 AS isVIP
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN order_header ON customer.customer_id = order_header.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.column1, .. , customer.columnN
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, the logic works but how do I append that to a column indicating 1 or 0? I need to return all rows in the customer table, regardless of if they are a VIP or not. Just an indicator.

Comment: @AJHalling My query does not filter the rows, so all customers will be displayed. The answer updated.

Comment: I just updated the post with my current query. As I noted, isVIP is false for every row. I thought I fixed the join, did I misplace something?

Comment: @AJHalling Add into the question: CREATE TABLE scripts, some sample data as INSERT INTO (3-4 customers) and desired output for this data (decreasing the amount of VIP to 3 for data amount to be not huge).

Answer (score 0):

The solution that ended up working:

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name, address_line_1, city, state_province, CASE WHEN ordercount >= 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_vip_customer
FROM (SELECT customer.customer_id, customer_name, address_line_1, city, state_province, count(order_header.customer_id) AS ordercount
    FROM customer
    LEFT JOIN order_header ON customer.customer_id = order_header.customer_id 
    GROUP BY customer.customer_id) AS vipTable
```